# React retains the input value after the page is refreshed and keeps it in local storage

Tags: reactjs, input, frontend, local-storage, refresh

I'm doing a feature using react, which saves text from input and automatically updates to local storage, I want even if I refresh the page the text in the input stays and the state doesn't reset from scratch. Thanks for helping me, have a nice day. please give me an the demo in the following codesandbox [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-not-reload-after-refreshing-6ckto). one more time thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you want to store your input's value in react state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
```

When the input changes, write the change to react state, and also localStorage

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
  localStorage.setItem("inputValue", e.target.value);
};
```

When the component is mounted, we want to set the initial state of the input to the value in localStorage

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue(localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));
}, []);
```

Finally, hook the handler to onChange, and use the React state as the form value

```
<input
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-not-reload-after-refreshing-forked-q84r8?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thank you so much, it is very straight forward

Comment: I would suggest that you instantly set value: `useState(localStorage.getItem("inputValue")`. Gives the same result. I guess this is less code, no need for an extra `useEffect`

Comment: No i still use useEffect, when the value of localstorage changed it will update the state instantly, if i remove it, it just render the previous component because it can listen to the change automatically, useState is designed for render the first mounted component

Comment: Thank you so much by the way for help me out Mario